# How to demonstrate a significant difference in a proportion

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion

I want to show that if you don't take enough biopsies from the oesophagus for certain patients then you are more likely to not detect an illness . The counts in the table are the number of investigations where a sufficient number of biopsies were taken (based on a threshold number) versus whether that investigation resulted in a diagnosis of Illness.

```
                                Illness No Illness
Insufficient number of biopsies  18        52
Sufficient number of biopsies    11        18
```

It seems obvious to me when looking at the table that you are much more likely to not pick up the disease with an insufficient number of biopsies but Chi-squared doesnt show this.

```
Illness<-c(18,11)
No_Illness<-c(52,18)
data.frame(Illness,No_Illness)
chisq.test(data.frame(EoE,No_EoE))
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the difference between ~26% and ~38% (insufficient and sufficient, respectively) which, given the number of counts, is not that much to make a convincing case.

```
prop.test(c(18, 11), c(70, 29), alternative= 'less')

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(18, 11) out of c(70, 29)
X-squared = 0.94659, df = 1, p-value = 0.1653
alternative hypothesis: less
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.00000000  0.07352868
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.2571429 0.3793103
```